# calculus / algebra

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Hi can anyone go through the transformation of the equation below as i cannot understand where the 2 in comes from  any help would be much appreciated

$$\frac{\omega k^{0.5}}{\omega k} = \frac{1}{2k^{0.5}}$$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: hi also it should be lower case delta but i dont think thats much of issue   i cancelled the like terms and ended up at 1 /k^0.5

Comment: No. May be you could use that if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$, then $ad=bc$ and start simplifying from here

Comment: Is this from some physics textbook? Share the context.

Answer (score 2):

The $2$ shouldn't be there.  It's a mistake.

Comment: i thought this also but this relates to latter question where totals are subbed in and the answers for that only work if is $2k^0.5$

Comment: hmm, well as a sanity check let's see what happens if $k = 4$.  On the left we have $2/4$, on the right we have $1/4$.  Definitely not equal.  Maybe the equation hasn't been transcribed correctly here or something.

Comment: thanks for your help i have re uploaded the problem on a new post with an image if that is of any help

Comment: Thanks.  I see in the image you posted that $\omega$ is supposed to be $\partial$, indicating that we are computing a partial derivative.  $\partial$ is not a number that cancels out.